# 2 degree polynomial problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, problem-solving

I'm not sure how to title this but here's the problem;

> Define $a,b,c$ so that $P(x) + Q(x) = 0$ with every value of $x$.
>
> $P(x) = 5x^2 - ax + 4 - (bx^2 - 7x + 3)$ and $Q(x) = 8x^2 + x + c$.

So you need to find values for $a, b$ and $c$ which will make the sum of $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ equal to zero, no matter what you will input as the value of $x$.

I've tried simplifying the sum of the polynomials but that's how far I'll get. I can deduce the correct answer by trying different values but i don't think it's how you are supposed to solve this problem.

How you should mathematically approach this problem? Can you create an equation out of this?

Comment: What have you tried? E.g. what is $P(x) + Q(x)$? What does it mean for this to "equal zero for every value of $x$"?

Comment: @CalvinLin You need to find a value for (a), (b) and (c) that will make P(x) + Q(x) = 0, no matter what you will input as the value of (x).

Comment: Great, so what is $P(x) + Q(x)$ equal to currently?

Comment: @CalvinLin You mean the simplified form? Then it's; 13x^2-bx^2+8x-ax+c+1

Comment: Great, so if this is equal to 0, what can we say about b? a? c?

Comment: @CalvinLin All i can think of is that the sum of -ax + c - bx^2 has to equal to 13x^2 + 8 + 1

Comment: Could $ a = 1$? Why, or why not? Could $ a = 8$? Why, or why not?

Comment: @CalvinLin I think a could be 8 because then the term -ax will match the +8 term.

Comment: @CalvinLin Also c = -1, because then it will match the +1 and by the same logic b = 13.

Comment: @CalvinLin I still don't see how x can be any value, for example the terms -ax matches +8 only if x = 1. Also i'm trying to think what is the correct formula or equation for this problem if there even is one? Or are you supposed to just deduce this answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116668/discussion-between-heineken-and-calvin-lin).

Comment: Tip: don't think about this as a 4-variable problem, because as a matter of fact, you have only one variable: $x$. $a, b, c$ are parameters, and you are looking for suitable parameter values so that they give a solution for any value of $x$, so that it remains a variable.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó That is true, didn't even think that. I should change the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general what you want to do is group the like terms.
What does $P(x)+Q(x)$ look like?
$P(x)+Q(x)=5x^2-ax+4-bx^2+7x-3+8x^2+x+c$
now we can group the like terms to have that this is equal to:
$(5-b+8)x^2+(-a+7+1)x+(4-3+c)$
we want this to equal zero, so in particular we need $(5-b+8)=0$, $(-a+7+1)=0$ and $(4-3+c)=0$.

The same strategy is how you would do this in general.

Comment: Yes. This is what i didn't understand to do. Thank you.